# Google maps xml result save to file

Tags: php

I am trying to save the xml results from google api into the file but from some reasons it doesen't work even if I want to display it on the screen. Any ideas?

```
<?php
$url ="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false";

if (file_exists($url)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
     print_r($xml); #  <-- Display in browser
} else {
    exit('Failed!');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `file_exists()` with a URL.  If you replace that with something like `file_get_contents()`, the rest of your code will work as expected.